# ImageMagick: How do I do a simple crop?

Tags: imagemagick

All I'm trying to do is crop images to a width of 1400 pixels from the left, but leave them at the same height.

The format should be width: 1400px, height 100% (unchanged), offset X and Y are both zero, so +0+0 (for X and Y):

```
convert -crop 1400x100%+0+0 inputfile outputfile
```

This doesn't actually do anything! Can someone help me with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The 100% isn't necessary. It should be:

convert -crop 1400x+0+0 inputfile outputfile

Comment: Read my answer. That command may work fine in ImageMagick 6, but not in ImageMagick 7. Read the input before the -crop.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax for ImageMagick is not correct. It may work in ImageMagick 6, which is forgiving, but not in ImageMagick 7. Read the input before any operations.

What you need to do is just specify Wx+0+0, without including H. That will tell ImageMagick, that you just want the width cropped. For example:

Lena:

[image]

convert lena.png -crop 100x+0+0 +repage result.png

[image]

Include +repage for those formats that support virtual canvas, such as PNG and TIFF. JPG does not need it, but it won't hurt.

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_percent